# How to exclude multiple Spring profiles in Kotlin?

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-profiles

I used this construction:

```
@Profile("!test")
```

Okay, but I need to set do not use this bean with multiple profiles. Insofar as value field is String[], I wrote this:

```
@Profile(value = ["!local", "!test"])
```

and get this exception:

> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'ru.example.service.AuthenticationService'
> available: expected single matching bean but found 2:
> testAuthenticationService,springAuthenticationService

As we see, the construction above not works. How to set profile in my case?

Comment: Did you put `@Profile("test")` on testAuthenticationService bean or Autowired ctor?

Comment: put on service.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is, can you try using `@Profile("!test & !local")`

Comment: My theory is that you have 2 profiles "!local" (includes test) and "!test" (includes local) so you need to have a single profile that excludes both instead

Comment: wow! it works! please, make correct answer on my queestion below, I shall accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Profile(value = ["!local", "!test"])` is the equivalent of `@Profile("!local | !test") meaning that only beans that are BOTH local and test are excluded.

What you need is `@Profile("!local & !test") to exclude either local or test.

This is an example of De Morgan's Law where `!(foo | bar) == !foo & !bar`, but you had `!foo | !bar == !(foo & bar)`.

Answer (score 0):

It works, but it is telling you that by having those two active profiles you have to beans of type `AuthenticationService` when only one is expected.
This is what you need to fix. `@Profile` with multiple profiles is working just fine.

Comment: dude, when I use @Profile("!test"), I have no problems. The problem is not that I have 2 beans. The problem is that @Profile not works with array.